# IONIC make sure that service is loaded before

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm programming an app with IONIC and typescript.
I created a storage provider and a network provider (see pseudocode below).

**Storage provider**

```
class SettingsService {
    settings;
    constructor(private storage: Storage) {
        storage.get("settings").then((data) => this.settings = data);
    }

    getSettings() {
        return this.settings;
    }
}
```

**Network provider**

```
class NetworkService {
    constructor(private http: http, private settingsService: SettingsService) {}

    getData() {
        settings = this.settingsService.getSettings();
        //Do more stuff
    }
}
```

When I now call the function `getData()` it can happen that settings is undefined because the SettingsService is still loading the settings. How can I wait in the NetworkProvider until the settings are fully loaded?

At the moment I'm using setTimeout to check if the settings are already loaded. But I'm not happy with this.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using promises?

Something like following:

```
class SettingsService {
    settings = null;

    constructor(private storage: Storage) {

    }

    getSettings(): Promise<{}> {

        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            if (settings !== null) {
              resolve(settings);
            } else {
              this.storage.get("settings").then((data) => {
                  this.settings = data
                  resolve(this.settings);
               });
            }
        });
    }
}

class NetworkService {
    constructor(private http: http, private settingsService: SettingsService) {}

    getData() {
       this.settingsService.getSettings().then((settings) => {
         //Do more stuff
       });
    }
  }
```

Also I think that storage performances are good, so maybe you could also spare the settings variable in SettingsService and just always get the value from storage...but I don't know your app of course, just an idea

P.S.: Don't forget that storage should only be used after the `platform.ready()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's working fine. But is there a way to wait until settings are loaded instead of loading them when they are not already loaded?

Comment: Cool to know it's working. I don't understand your question sorry. Doing `this.storage.get("settings").then((data)  =>` gonna let you wait for the data to be loaded

Comment: My bad, sorry. Actually I'm loading the settings in the constructor of the SettingsService and in the method getSettings() I'm doing some stuff on the settings before returning them. So I want to wait in getSettings until the constructor has finished loading the settings.

Comment: Mmmmh maybe you have to change your code to amend the fact that getting the values from storage is done thru promise

Answer (score 0):

Storage provider

```
class SettingsService {
    settings;
    constructor(private storage: Storage) {}

    getSettings() {
        return storage.get("settings");          
}
```

Network provider

```
class NetworkService {
    constructor(private http: http, private settingsService: SettingsService) {}

    getData() {
      let settings;
       this.settingsService.getSettings().subscribe(_settings => settings=_settings;

    }
}
```